# WordPress: set image max-width: 100% with Twenty-Twentythree theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can you see [the image](https://unitscan.org) I used as the header?
From the CSS we know that in order for an image to cover the entire width of the screen it is necessary to set the style max-width: 100%.
Using the Simple Custom CSS plugin I wrote

```
.wp-block-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn’t seem to work. I'm running WordPress 6.1 with Twenty-Twentythree theme.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: What do you see when you use your browser devtools inspect factility - exactly what CSS is being applied from where? And why not set the width to 100vw?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can **Group** the block(s) and set alignment to **full width**.

[Example of creating a full-width block in Twenty Twenty-Three WordPress theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGuG.png)

*(apparently I don't have enough reputation points to display image inline with answer)*